# Copying the fields of one record into the fields of another record in a second file with awk

Tags: awk

GNU Awk 5.1.0. zsh, Ubuntu 22.04
I have file containing 1 record
`record_grab.tmp`

```
XJZT+ML+SD         | 9979 | 4¾    | 14
```

and file
`table.txt`

```
| formula               | no. | dose     | days    |
| --------------------- | --- | -------- | ------- |
|                       |     |          |         |
```

I want to place fields 1,2,3,4 from `record_grab.tmp` in fields 1,2,3,4 of record 3 of `table.txt`. Preserving the formatting and record separators of `table.txt`.

I have used the chain of commands in the terminal as follows:

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$0}' /tmp/record_grab.tmp 
|awk -v FS='|' -v OFS='|'  'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4 a[FNR], $3}' /tmp/record_grab.tmp /home/table.txt
```

The result was:

```
| formula               | no. | dose      XJZT+ML+SD          | 9979 | 4¾    | 14    | no. 
| --------------------- | --- | -------- | --- 
|                       |     |
```

The expected result is:

```
| formula               | no.  | dose     | days    |
| --------------------- | ---  | -------- | ------- |
| XJZT+ML+SD            | 9979 | 4¾       | 14      |
```

I realise there is definitely a more elegant way to do this, that aside I have made a mistake in my use of arrays it looks like it's put the entire line from the temp file into field 3 of table.txt rather than record 3 somehow and I can't work out how to correct it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have edited to add contents of table.txt. Cut down question to minimal reproducible example

Comment: What happened to `source_file.txt`? IIRC `/tmp/record_grab.tmp` was an intermediate temp file that you don't actually need that you were producing from `source_file.txt` in your code. If that's true then you should make your starting point `source_file.txt` and `table.txt` so you don't need `/tmp/record_grab.tmp` and the code that creates it. You also already have multiple answers that assume `source_file.txt` is a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
19-03-2024
Name            | formula           | no.  | dose | days | cost  | msg | em | notes | consult | WYLQ
John Doe        | XJZT+ML+SD        | 9979 | 4¾   | 14   | xx.xx | x   | 2  | xx    | ph      |
Jane Doe        | XJZT-BS+CS+MDP+FL | 9980 | 5    | 10   | xx.xx | x   | 1  | xx    | ph      |
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==2{print "|" $2,$3,$4,$5 "|";for(i=2;i<=5;i+=1){$i=sprintf("%*s",length($i),"");gsub(/ /,"-",$i)};print "|" $2,$3,$4,$5 "|"}NR>2&&$1~/John Doe/{print "|" $2,$3,$4,$5 "|"}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
| formula           | no.  | dose | days |
|-------------------|------|------|------|
| XJZT+ML+SD        | 9979 | 4¾   | 14   |
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that pipe is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`), for 2nd line I print desired columns encased in `|`. Then for each selected column I use dynamic `sprintf` to get string consisting of as many spaces as there characters in given column, which I then globally substitute using dashes. I `print` it in some manner as headers line. For each line after 2nd line and having `John Doe` inside 1st field I `print` desired column encased in `|`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: I wish you would use some white space in your scripts, I'd love to be able to understand some of them as I think there might be some good information in them. If you ran `gawk -o-` on your script and then replaced your 1 line of continuous characters with it's output, it'd be vastly easier for us to read and understand and no more effort for you to write.

Answer (score 1):

This, using any awk, is an untested guess (since no example of table.txt in the question) at what you might be trying to do:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
    NR == FNR {
        if ( $1 ~ /John Doe/ ) {
            split($0,a)
            nextfile
        }
        next
    }
    FNR == 3 {
        for ( i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
            $i = a[i+1]
        }
    }
    { print }
' source_file.txt table.txt
```

If your awk supports the non-POSIX extension `nextfile` the above will execute faster than if it doesn't, but it'll work either way.

Comment: if you're all that concerned about the time savings from `nextfile`, then perhaps try `index($1, "John Doe")` instead of a `regex` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- you want to create a new file (`table.txt`) that consists of fields 2-5 from the input file `source_file.txt`
- you're only interested in source lines reprsenting the column headers, or lines where the `Name` column includes the string `John Doe`
- each new line of output is to include a prefix/suffix of `|`

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN              { FS=OFS="|" }
$1~/Name|John Doe/ { print OFS $2,$3,$4,$5 OFS}
' source_file.txt > table.txt
```

This generates:

```
$ cat table.txt
| formula           | no.  | dose | days |
| XJZT+ML+SD        | 9979 | 4¾   | 14   |
```

**NOTES:**

- `/Name|John Does/` will also match on strings like `John No Name Given` and `John Does Dallas`; if this could be an issue then we could expand the code to match exact strings
- expected output includes a line of hyphens (to separate header from data) but there's no attempt in OP's current code to create said line of hyphens so I've opted to *not* add code to create said line; if the line of hyphens is required we'd need to add more code